# Can I update a Jenkins Global Environment Variable from a pipeline script?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

If I define an environment variable (eg. VersionNum) under Jenkins Global Properties, can I update the value within a pipeline script?  I was hoping to use it to store version information and update according to script execution results.

What I want to do is write a pipeline script like:

```
node {
    stage {'Stage1') {
        VersionNum = '5'
    }
}
```

that will update the global environment variable so the new value that will persist and can be used by other Jenkins jobs.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you tried it?

Comment: I've used it for years, but have never needed to ask a question until now.

Comment: What do you mean? Jenkins or storing a global variable from a pipeline?

Comment: This thread does what you're asking, although it isn't accomplished via a pipeline directly and I believe it requires you to have already created the global environment variable:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/KgCGuDmED1Q

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try to use the global environment variable, I read a properties file with the Pipeline Utility Steps plugin:

```
def props = readProperties  file:"${WORKSPACE}\\BuildVersion.properties" 
MajVersion = props['MAJOR_VERSION'].trim()
MinVersion = props['MINOR_VERSION'].trim()
```

Then if I change a value, I write it back with:

```
bat "(echo MAJOR_VERSION=${MajVersion} && echo MINOR_VERSION=${MinVersion}) \u003E \"%WORKSPACE%\\BuildVersion.properties\""
```

Comment: But how do you change a value and write it back in Linux